# could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled on windows

Tags: git, go

I was trying to fetch some dependencies from a private repository using `go get -u <github_private_repo_link>` but it keeps on failing with this error:

```
server response:
not found: github.com/..../v3@v3.11.1: invalid version: git ls-remote -q origin in /tmp/gopath/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/168bff8af96cdfac9cbe3ad64f7753732f8a19d99f7f1e897f19371e1ea453d9: exit status 128:
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
Confirm the import path was entered correctly.
If this is a private repository, see https://golang.org/doc/faq#git_https for additional information.
```

I've tried to export `set GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=1` but nothing happens, the same error is issued. Is there any way go get will ignore the value of this variable on windows for `go 1.13`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try setting a temporary credential handler for GitHub:

```
GIT_USER="your-github-username-or-email"
GIT_PASS="PAT"

git config --global credential.helper "!f() { echo \`"username=`${GIT_USER}`npassword=`${GIT_PASS}\`"; }; f"
```

Or install the github cli and authenticate to github using `gh auth login`.

And [check out the docs mentioned in the error message for other options](https://go.dev/doc/faq#git_https):

Git can be configured to authenticate over HTTPS or to use SSH in place of HTTPS. To authenticate over HTTPS, you can add a line to the `$HOME/.netrc` file that git consults:

```
machine github.com login USERNAME password APIKEY
```

For GitHub accounts, the password can be a personal access token.

Git can also be configured to use SSH in place of HTTPS for URLs matching a given prefix. For example, to use SSH for all GitHub access, add these lines to your `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[url "ssh://git@github.com/"]
    insteadOf = https://github.com/
```